# VBA - Speed Up Uploading Data to SQL from VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I’m using a macro that writes data to a SQL Table everyday. Problem is that usually I have more than 300k rows to upload and Macro runs very slowly (more than 60 minutes). Is there anyway to speed up this process? Below part of the code, this is exactly where Macro spent most of time:

```
 tb = "[Table_Test]"
    Set Pos = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(“Sheet1”)
    For i = 3 To last_row

        query = "INSERT INTO " & tb & " ([DATE],[POSITION])"
        query2 = " VALUES " & "('" & Format(CDate(Pos.Cells(i, 1)), "yyyy-mm-dd") & "'" & ", '" & Pos.Cells(i, 2) & "'" &");"
        query = query & query2
        Execute_SQL_218 (query)
        query = False
        Application.StatusBar = "Uploading Data To SQL..." & i
        DoEvents
    Next i
```

Comment: What DB are you using?

Comment: Removing `Application.StatusBar` update and `DoEvents` could significantly trim the execution time already, but it wouldn't surprise me if bulk-inserting the records with an `INSERT INTO... SELECT` query, i.e. querying your worksheet through ODBC rather than generating one `INSERT` statement per row, would bring the whole thing down to under a minute.

Comment: Also `query2` is redundant, just use a `_` line continuation, no need to concatenate `query & query2`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this loop sends the data to the server row-by-row and runs a query for each. You need to send the whole thing as one recordset and insert it with one query.
As you did not provide what kind of SQL DB you have, I can only give you one suggestion for Microsoft SQL Server: first export your recordset to .csv file then instead of running the "INSERT INTO " query run a [BULK INSERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer! I'm using Microsoft SQL SERVEr, I'll try the bulk insert solution, thanks.

Comment: You can only use bulk insert if you can save the csv or text file directly on to the machine that hosts SQL server, as you can not bulk insert into SQL from a file located on a remote server location.